# How To Get Control Value From BackGroundWorker

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I want to access control (eg: textbox, label etc ) value from backgroundworker. I can easily set control value from backgroundworker. But now need get method to retrieve control value.

Here is my code...

```
Private Sub mySQLgetSET_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles mySQLgetSET.DoWork

    Dim lCount As Integer
    Try

        If conn.State = 0 Then conn.Open()

        If conn.State = 1 Then
            mySQLgetSET.ReportProgress(1, New ControlWithText(lblNetConnection_status, "Connected"))
            lblNetConnection_status.ForeColor = Color.Green
        End If
        If conn.State = 1 Then
            If modem_count > 0 Then
                mySQLgetSET.ReportProgress(1, New ControlWithText(lblNetConnection_status, "Connected"))
                lblNetConnection_status.ForeColor = Color.Green



                mySQLgetSET.ReportProgress(1, New ControlWithText(lblloadque, "Pending request: " & lvRec.Items.Count))

                'Load data from server
                If Not lvRec.Items.Count > 0 Then
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
                    Me.lvRec.Items.Clear()
                    Dim SqlCmd As String = ""
                    SqlCmd = "select * from  send_query where operator like '%GP%' and status='0'  Order by ID asc"
                    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(SqlCmd, conn)
                    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

                    While reader.Read()
                        'Add Data to Listview from backgroundworker
                        ListViewAddItem(Me.lvRec, _
                                        reader.GetString("id"), _
                                        reader.GetString("load_type"), _
                                        reader.GetString("phone"), _
                                        reader.GetString("balance"), _
                                        reader.GetString("user_id"), _
                                        Format(TimeOfDay, "HH:mm:ss"))


                        Application.DoEvents()
                        mySQLgetSET.ReportProgress(1, New ControlWithText(lbldataloading, "Loading Request: " & lvRec.Items.Count))


                    End While
                    reader.Close()
                    mySQLgetSET.ReportProgress(1, New ControlWithText(lbldataloading, "Total Request: " & lvRec.Items.Count))

                ElseIf lvRec.Items.Count > 0 Then

                    mySQLgetSET.ReportProgress(1, New ControlWithText(lblloadque, "Pending request: " & lvRec.Items.Count))

                    For i As Int32 = 0 To modem_count - 1

                        If txt_coredata_servertxt(i).Text = "" And txt_Update_4(i).Text = "" Then
                            Try
                               If StopThread(i) = False And txt_coredata_servertxt(i).Text = "" And txt_Update_4(i).Text = "" Then

                                    Dim newData As String

                                    '***************************************************************
                                    'Here is my problem. I want to acceaa listView Item 
                                    'lvRec is my listView

                                    newData = lvRec.Items(i).SubItems.Item(1).Text
                                    '***************************************************************

                                End If

                                'lblloadque.Text = "Pending request: " & lvRec.Items.Count
                                mySQLgetSET.ReportProgress(1, New ControlWithText(lblloadque, "Pending request: " & lvRec.Items.Count))
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                MsgBox(ex.Message)
                                txt_coredata_servertxt(i).Text = ""

                                mySQLgetSET.ReportProgress(1, New ControlWithText(lblloadque, "Pending request: " & lvRec.Items.Count))
                            End Try
                        End If
                        Application.DoEvents()
                    Next

                    'Checked to Remove Data
                    For lCount = lvRec.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                        'If lvRec.Items(lCount).Checked Then
                        '    lvRec.Items(lCount).Remove()
                        'End If
                        'mySQLgetSET.ReportProgress(1, New ControlWithText(lbldataloading, "Total Request: " & lvRec.Items.Count))
                        Application.DoEvents()
                    Next

                End If
            End If

        End If
        If conn.State = 1 Then conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Me.Text = conn.State.ToString
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        If conn.State = 0 Then
            mySQLgetSET.ReportProgress(100, New ControlWithText(lblNetConnection_status, "Conecting>>"))

            'lblNetConnection_status.Text = "Conecting>>"
            lblNetConnection_status.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        End If
    End Try
    If conn.State = 1 Then conn.Close()


End Sub
```

Comment: A DoEvents in a BackgroundWorker?  Sleeping, too?  It's not really background work if you are doing UI work.  Try to only work on the "data" in the BackgroundWorker and bubble up UI actions to the ReportProgess method and RunWorkerCompleted events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually we use backgroundworker RunWorkerCompleted event to handle data but you can have a look 
Virtual Treeview Implementation and specially the "#Region Asynchronous Treeview". It will solve your problem. Here is link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20552/Virtual-Treeview-Implementation